# What is causing this error with Square integration

Tags: javascript, json, square

I'm building my first integration with Squareup.com.  In the docs as shown in their walkthrough page (https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/payment-form-walkthrough), I've copied the code as instructed but I there's an error coming from the 'catch error' in the callbacks.

[update]

OK so having been told applicationID was wrong, we have discovered that its the process-payment file that is empty and that is causing the error.  I reinstalled npm and started it and we're chugging along :)

Final questions....

I'm thinking server.js needs to be updated with the data of the specific order. At what stage is it best to do that - presumably when card details are submitted within a hidden parameter.  But what name should it be given? I haven't found anything in the docs.

[/update]

Thanks for comments and, in response, here's the complete code.

```
<body>
    <div id="form-container">
      <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
      <div class="third" id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
      <div class="third" id="sq-cvv"></div>
      <div class="third" id="sq-postal-code"></div>
      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="onGetCardNonce(event)">Pay $1.00</button>
    </div> 
    <!-- end #form-container --> 


<script type="text/javascript">

    const idempotency_key = uuidv4();


    // Create and initialize a payment form object
    const paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
    // Initialize the payment form elements
   
    applicationId: "edited-out-for-security",
    inputClass: 'sq-input',
    autoBuild: false,
    
    // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
    inputStyles: [{
       fontSize: '16px',
       lineHeight: '24px',
       padding: '16px',
       placeholderColor: '#a0a0a0',
       backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    }],
   
  // Initialize the credit card placeholders
  cardNumber: {
       elementId: 'sq-card-number',
       placeholder: 'Card Number'
  },
  cvv: {
       elementId: 'sq-cvv',
       placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
       elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
       placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
       elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
       placeholder: 'Postal'
  },
  // SqPaymentForm callback functions
  callbacks: {
       /*
       * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
       * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
       */
       cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
       if (errors) {
           // Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer console.
           console.error('Encountered errors:');
           errors.forEach(function (error) {
               console.error('  ' + error.message);
           });
           alert('Encountered errors, check browser developer console for more details');
            return;
       }
       
       
      fetch('/cgi-bin/square-payment-processor/process-payment', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
               'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          nonce: nonce,
          idempotency_key: idempotency_key,
          location_id: "edited-out-for-security"
      })   
  })

.catch(err => {
  alert('Network error: ' + err);  
})
.then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
    return response.json().then(
      errorInfo => Promise.reject(errorInfo));
  }
return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  alert('Payment complete successfully!\nCheck browser developer 
console for more details'); 
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
  alert('Payment failed to complete!\nCheck browser developer console for more details');
});

    }
  }
});

paymentForm.build();
 
//Generate a random UUID as an idempotency key for the payment request
// length of idempotency_key should be less than 45
function uuidv4() {
   return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, 
    function(c) {
       var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
       return v.toString(16);
    });
}


// onGetCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay $1.00" button is clicked
function onGetCardNonce(event) {

  // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
  event.preventDefault();
  // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
  paymentForm.requestCardNonce();  
}





</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are probably getting an HTML error page instead of a JSON response.  Look at your browser dev tools for the actual response.  Your question doesn't contain enough information for us to offer anything further, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why are you showing us your exception handler and not the exception itself? Where's the code that parses the JSON object?

Comment: I appreciate you adding your code, but have you looked at the response as suggested?

Comment: Thanks Amy. I've added the console.log result in the second section of code. It appears to be undefined yet it seems all the data to be submitted is correct. Stingified json is correctly filled.

Comment: No, that isn't good enough.  Your error says it starts with a `<`, so `undefined` is not at all helpful.  You need actual diagnostics.  Look at the network tab in your dev tools at the **actual** response you are receiving.

Comment: Thnks. switched to FF and have posted what I found in Orig msg.

Comment: Okay, a 401 Unauthorized means you should be sending some credentials with the request, but they aren't accepting them.  Either you aren't sending, or they've expired, or something to that effect.

Comment: Thanks Amy very much. I'll get on to square bcoz I'm using the credentials as per their sandbox.

Comment: Orig post updated with new info. Hoping, with someone's help, I can get through this really clunky setup.